# How to add new menu category in FreePBX

Tags: php, freepbx

I was trying to add new menu category in FreePBX Version 13.

I tried all the possibilities.

1. Referred the freePBX menu documentation at http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FOP/FreePBX+Menu+Conf
2. Created the category in module.xml like below:

> <ucptab access="all" category="User Panel" href="/ucp"
>   requires_auth="false" target="ucp">UCP</ucptab>

Where user Panel is the new category. FreePBX is not considering any other categories except Admin, Applications, Connectivity, Reports.

I have been trying to add modules to new category for the past 2 days but none of the standards worked for me. Need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Hi Divakar, If you are using FreePBX 2.10 check out freepbx_menu.conf.template. This will allow you to customize the menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got `<ucptab>` from but this is how you would do it. Note that if this is the only item in the category, you won't get a dropdown, just a single button labeled "My Module"

```
<category>My Category</category>
<menuitems>
    <mymodule>My Module</mymodule>
</menuitems>
```